# Problems with parsing decaf (variable declaration versus constructor)

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, context-free-grammar, bisonc++

I am using bison (3.0.4) and lexer to implement the (partial) grammar of Decaf programming language. I am only implementing what is inside the class.

So, my task is simple: store every production rule (as a string) in the tree, and then just print it out.

For example, if you have the following line of code as an input

`class Foo { Foo(int arg1) { some2 a; } }`

you (must) get the following output

```
<ClassDecl>         --> class identifier <classBody>
<ClassBody>         --> { <VariableDecl>* <ConstructorDecl>* <MethodDecl>* }
<ConstructorDecl>   --> identifier ( <ParameterList> ) <Block>
<ParameterList>     --> <Parameter> <, Parameter>*
<Parameter>         --> <Type> identifier
<Type>              --> <SimpleType>
<SimpleType>        --> int
<Block>             --> { <LocalVariableDecl>* <Statement>* }
<LocalVariableDecl> --> <Type> identifier ;
<Type>              --> <SimpleType>
<SimpleType>        --> identifier
```

The first problem (solved) was that it parsed **variable declaration** instead of **constructor declaration**, though I have no variable declaration in the scope of a class itself (i.e. I have only inside the constructor's block). This is solved.

Nevertheless, if I give the following `class abc { some1 abc; john doe; }` it says that `syntax error, unexpected SEMICOLON, expecting LP`. So, the character at line 19 causes the problem.

Here is **.y** file (only **classBody** rule)

```
class_decl:
  CLASS ID LC class_body RC
  ;


/* FIXME: Gotta add more grammar here */
class_body: var_declmore constructor_declmore method_declmore
  | var_declmore constructor_declmore
  | var_declmore method_declmore
  | constructor_declmore method_declmore
  | method_declmore
  | var_declmore
  | constructor_declmore
  | %empty
  ;


var_declmore: var_decl
  | var_declmore var_decl
  ;


constructor_declmore: constructor_decl
  | constructor_declmore constructor_decl 
  ;

var_decl: type ID SEMICOLON
  | type ID error
  ;

constructor_decl: ID LP parameter_list RP block
  | ID error parameter_list RP block
  ;
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4be8375eca2f1675c4897fed027e25b7) to the full *.y* file.

Comment: I got a ton of warnings from that file. Including two shift-reduce conflicts; one reduce-reduce conflict; and a warning about a useless rule. BTW, it is a lot easier to read a grammar if you leave out the actions; see [mcve]

Comment: You will get a lot of warnings because rules such as **expression**, **name** and **new_expression** are not used yet. They are used in the **statement** rule, which has not been implemented yet as I want to figure out the problem with this rule (**vardecl and constructor conflict**).

Comment: You will find that much easier if you create a [mcve] with only the applicable rules.

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem is that `constructor_declmore` can be empty, and that both `var_decl` and `constructor_decl` can start with `ID`.

That's a problem because before the parser can recognize a `constructor_decl`, it needs to reduce an (empty) `constructor_declmore`.  But it obviously cannot do that reduction unless it knows that the  `var_declmore` is finished.

So when it sees an `ID` it has to decide between one of two actions:

1. Reduce an empty `constructor_declmore`, thereby deciding that there are no more `var_decl`s; or
2. Shift the `ID` in order to start parsing a new `var_decl`.

In the absence of precedence declarations (which wouldn't help here), bison/yacc always resolves shift/reduce conflicts in favour of the shift action. So in this case, it assumes that `Foo` is the `ID` which starts a `var_decl`, leading to the error message you note.

The reduce/reduce conflict produced by the grammar should also be looked at. It comes from the `method_declmore: method_decl` rule, which conflicts with the other possible way of creating a `method_declmore` by starting with an empty `method_declmore` and then adding a `method_decl`.

Comment: That's true. But, as I changed the rule for **classBody**, now it tries to match the **constructor_decl** rule, though I give the variable declaration. Check for the edit.

Comment: @alwaysone: please don't change questions after they are answered. If you have a new question, ask it separately.

Comment: It did not solve my problem with the **classBody** definition, thus question is not fully answered. I am not changing it drastically because the same problem with proper declaration of **classBody** persists.

Comment: It answered your question *as asked*. It did not fix all the problems with your grammar. Regardless,it addressed a not uncommon problem, so it could have helped someone else, except that the question no longer shows the problem, making it useless for future visitors.

Comment: Someone may have had the same set of rules (grammar), but imagine if someone checks this answer and it's not completely answered because problem with one of the rules still persists. Therefore, it does not matter that I changed the question because in both cases it won't work as it still does not. You helped a lot with a direction, and helped with only a subproblem of a bigger problem to which I asked at least a direction. In short, you helped with one thing, however, the main problem is still there.

Comment: @alwaysnone: Fwiw, I think your new problem has to do with method_decl and the uncertain decision between reducing rsult_type or simple_type. So it is a different problem. Anyway, good luck with it.

Comment: i will accept your answer, not a problem. I would appreciate though if you could help solve the question as a whole. The thing is that it goes now into **constructor_decl**, though I gave it the **variable_decl**. Probably, there is something wrong with the position of **ID** token.

Comment: @alwaysnone: as i said, i'm pretty sure the new conflict is related to method declarations conflicting with variable declarations but that part of the grammar is not in this question. I can only reiterate the suggestion that you ask a different question corresponding to the different problem. ("My program doesn't work; help me fix all the problems" is not a question which fits your into SO's structure.)

Comment: actually, the problem was with **type**, not method declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158187/discussion-between-rici-and-alwaysone).